# load left nav in ajax request

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ajax

in my template for load category left block after load page by ajax use this method

```
    public function viewAction()
{

    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() && (!$this->getRequest()->getParam("fullpageajax") || $this->getRequest()->getParam("ajaxcatalog") || $this->getRequest()->getParam("infinite"))){ //Check if it was an AJAX request
        $response = array();
        if ($category = $this->_initCatagory()) {
            $design = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/design');
            $settings = $design->getDesignSettings($category);

            // apply custom design
            if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
                $design->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
            }

            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setLastViewedCategoryId($category->getId());

            $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
            $update->addHandle('default');

            if (!$category->hasChildren()) {
                $update->addHandle('catalog_category_layered_nochildren');
            }

            $this->addActionLayoutHandles();
            $update->addHandle($category->getLayoutUpdateHandle());
            $update->addHandle('CATEGORY_' . $category->getId());
            $this->loadLayoutUpdates();

            // apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
            if ($layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates()) {
                if (is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                    foreach($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                        $update->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                    }
                }
            }



        $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks(); //Generate new blocks

        $viewpanel =  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();
        ///error is here

        $productlist = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->toHtml(); // Generate product list

        $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
        $response['viewpanel']=$viewpanel;
        $response['productlist'] = $productlist;

        // apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
        }elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
            $response['status'] = 'FAILURE';
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
    }

    if ($category = $this->_initCatagory()) {
        $design = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/design');
        $settings = $design->getDesignSettings($category);

        // apply custom design
        if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
            $design->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setLastViewedCategoryId($category->getId());

        $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $update->addHandle('default');

        if (!$category->hasChildren()) {
            $update->addHandle('catalog_category_layered_nochildren');
        }

        $this->addActionLayoutHandles();
        $update->addHandle($category->getLayoutUpdateHandle());
        $update->addHandle('CATEGORY_' . $category->getId());
        $this->loadLayoutUpdates();

        // apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
        if ($layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates()) {
            if (is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                foreach($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                    $update->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();
        // apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
        if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
            $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyTemplate($settings->getPageLayout());
        }

        if ($root = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')) {
            $root->addBodyClass('categorypath-' . $category->getUrlPath())
            ->addBodyClass('category-' . $category->getUrlKey());
        }

        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
        $this->_forward('noRoute');
    }
}
```

but this line create error

```
            $viewpanel =  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();
```

is there any way to replace this part with other same  code ?

Comment: Was something wrong with formating edits?

Comment: is it impotent that a statement started with Load or load ...edit just for L or  l ???

Comment: Also corrected some line intents for better readability. :) If you have found a soulution please accept your own answer.

Comment: i think i can not accept my answer ...is it imposible ? @s

Comment: It is possible ... maybe not enough reputation yet?

Comment: yes ...you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer and put it here for other developer

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->setTemplate('catalog/navigation/left.phtml')->toHtml();
```